# Is there a tutorial on how to create a simple external javascript widget?

Tags: javascript, html, css, widget

- Web developer pastes my javascript code in their HTML
- My widget gets the page's url, and on the server, looks up the URL's info, and returns a widget for that page.

How can I create that javascript?

Comment: I just want a simple JSONP widget javascript tutorial, but I googled it and couldn't find a simple tutorial that teaches me how to create a simple widget.

Comment: Are you looking to create something similar to website statistics widgets? They seem to do what you described, unless I misunderstood your question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows a lack of effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any tutorial, but this is what you could do.

There are 2 pieces required for this to work.

1. An initial script that gets loaded (the one the developer includes in their code)
2. A second script that is generated on the server and is then loaded onto the page by the first script

The first script will need to get the domain properties and pass those as url paramaters when requesting the second script.

```
// script one
// helperscript.js
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.type= 'text/javascript';
script.src= 'http://www.yourdomain.com/newscript.php?domain=' + 
     encodeURIComponent(location.hostname);
head.appendChild(script);
```

Then on the server (in this case i'll use php), you just get the url paramater and do what you need with it. Just as an example I'll make the new script run an alert function with the domain as its value.

```
//php generating script
//newscript.php
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/x-javascript', true); // so the browser knows this is javascript, even though the file has a .php extension
?> 
alert(<?php echo $_GET['domain']; ?>);
```

Thats it :)

So your html page will look something like this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://www.yourdomain.com/helperscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If you need more clarification leave a comment. Also I have not tested this code, so there may be a few bugs, but the method is correct.